# Discord-api "PATCH Modify Guild Member" didn't make any changes, when i make a PATCH with Google-Scripts: “UrlFetchApp.fetch()”

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, discord

I'm setting up a api connection. I have already an OAuth-authentication and a bot for my app. Now I want to make changes on discord Guild Member Role.

I make a PATCH and it return an 204. According to discord: "Returns a 204 empty response on success". But the don't get an update. No changes at Role.

Here is my "PATCH function":

```
function patchGuildMemberRole( userId, callback) {
  var API_ModifyGuildMember_URL = 'https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/500000000000000000/members/' + userId;
  data = {
    "roles": ["600000000000000000", "600000000000000000"]
  };
  header = {
    'method' : 'PATCH',
    'Authorization': 'Bot' + ' ' + 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'followRedirects' : true,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'payload' : data
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_ModifyGuildMember_URL, {headers: header});
  console.log("result");
  console.log(result);
  if (result.getResponseCode() == 204 || result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var params = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
    return callback(params);
  } else {
    return callback(error('API fetch error'));
  }
}
```

Here is my Response: "params":

```
{
  "nick": "Kevin - Kevin",
  "user": {
    "username": "Kevin",
    "discriminator": "6666",
    "id": "500000000000000000", "avatar": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz80acd5bb1a005"
  },
  "roles": ["500000000000000000"],
  "premium_since": null,
  "deaf": false,
  "mute": false,
  "joined_at": "2016-04-00T00:00:00.000000+00:00"
}
```

We want to update the roles to :
["600000000000000000", "600000000000000000"]

but we only have the old roles:
["500000000000000000"]

Answer (score 2):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
header = {
  'method' : 'PATCH',
  'Authorization': 'Bot' + ' ' + 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'followRedirects' : true,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'payload' : data
};
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_ModifyGuildMember_URL, {headers: header});
```

#### To:

```
var params = {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {Authorization: 'Bot' + ' ' + 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'},
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload : JSON.stringify(data)
};
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_ModifyGuildMember_URL, params);
```

- Please put out `method` and `payload` from the headers.
- You can use `contentType` instead of `Content-Type`. In this case, this is not required to be in the headers.
- In your case, `contentType` is `application/json`.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

### Edit:

When the error of `{"message": "Missing Permissions", "code": 50013}` with the status code of `403` occurs, please check the following point.

- At "Server settings", open "Roles".

  - **The order of roles are important for your situation.**
  - When it supposes that the role of Bot and the roles you want to give is "ForBot" and "sampleRole1" and "sampleRole2", respectively, if the order of Roles are as follows, the error of `{"message": "Missing Permissions", "code": 50013}` with the status code of `403` occurs.

    - **From**

      [image]
  - If the order of Roles are as follows, no error with the status code of `204` occurs. The request works.

    - **To**

      [image]

From above point, please confirm the order of Roles of your settings. And for example, please move the role of bot to the top of all roles by the drag and drop, and try to run the script again. When you modify the order of role, please don't forget to save it.

#### Reference:

- [Modify Guild Member](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild-member)

Comment: I tried your version. Now I get closer to the problem.
Discord returns a 403 {"message": "Missing Permissions", "code": 50013}
i don't know what permissions I missed. I tried with the discord scopes:
identify, guilds, guilds.join, bot.
Bot permissions:
manage server, manage roles, create instant invite.

Comment: Same permission problem with the Discord api PUT: Add Guild Member Role on /guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}/roles/{role.id}

Comment: @Luigi Diablo Thank you for replying. From the error message of your replying, it is found that the request works with the modified script. Actually, in my environment, I could confirm that the modified script worked. I think that your new issue of `Missing Permissions` is due to your settings. So I added the checkpoint in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: You hit exactly my problem. With your help I could fix the problem. Thank you so much. You are a so friendly awesome skilled dude! Have a nice day and stay that way.